# What is this heave brush-like typeface called?

Tags: font-identification

[image]

Hi guys can anyone help to identify this font? I want to use on my next project.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. Please read [our requirements for font-identification questions](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366) and edit your question accordingly, lest it be closed.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's called Meat Bold. You can find it [here](http://www.whatfontis.com/Meat-Bold-borutta.font?text=BRUTAL).

To be honest, you can easily find this font by uploading your image to What Font is. So next time you need to identify a font, look around before asking someone else to do it for you.

[image: Meat Bold]